# I am trying to create a table but its not getting created. The issue is with constraints. Mostly NOT NULL and FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
Cust_Id Number(4),
Cust_First_Name  VarChar2(20),
Cust_Mid_Name VarChar2(20),
Cust_Last_Name VarChar2(20),            
Account_Type Varchar2(15),          
Cust_Email VarChar2(30),                
Cust_Mobile Number(10),
Bank_Id NUMBER(4),
Account_No Number(4),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Id_Pri_Key PRIMARY KEY (Cust_Id),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Last_Name_Not_Null NOT NULL (Cust_Last_Name),
CONSTRAINT Cust_First_Name_Not_Null NOT NULL (Cust_First_Name),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Email_Unq UNIQUE(Cust_Email),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Mobile_Unq UNIQUE(Cust_Mobile),
CONSTRAINT Bank_Id_For_Key FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES bank(bankId)
);
```

Comment: whats the error say?

Comment: A primary key cannot have nulls in any database I have ever worked with.

Answer (score 2):

#### Working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05311

Here's how your SQL should look like.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
Cust_Id Number(4) NOT NULL,
Cust_First_Name  VarChar2(20) NOT NULL,
Cust_Mid_Name VarChar2(20),
Cust_Last_Name VarChar2(20) NOT NULL,            
Account_Type Varchar2(15),          
Cust_Email VarChar2(30),                
Cust_Mobile Number(10),
Bank_Id NUMBER(4),
Account_No Number(4),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Id_Pri_Key PRIMARY KEY (Cust_Id),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Email_Unq UNIQUE(Cust_Email),
CONSTRAINT Cust_Mobile_Unq UNIQUE(Cust_Mobile),
CONSTRAINT Bank_Id_For_Key FOREIGN KEY (Bank_Id) REFERENCES bank(bankId)  
);
```

Almost all your errors are from the Syntax.

- `NOT NULL` is specified in the Column name itself, not as a separate constraint.
- `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT requires you to specify the source column name, and the` FOREIGN KEY`column in the table that it is defined as a`PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: you can't specify `NOT NULL` as an out-of-line constraint and you are missing the column name in the foreign key constraint. The following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
   cust_id NUMBER (4),
   cust_first_name VARCHAR2 (20) CONSTRAINT cust_first_name_not_null NOT NULL,
   cust_mid_name VARCHAR2 (20),
   cust_last_name VARCHAR2 (20) CONSTRAINT cust_last_name_not_null NOT NULL,
   account_type VARCHAR2 (15),
   cust_email VARCHAR2 (30),
   cust_mobile NUMBER (10),
   bank_id NUMBER (4),
   account_no NUMBER (4),
   CONSTRAINT cust_id_pri_key PRIMARY KEY (cust_id),
   CONSTRAINT cust_email_unq UNIQUE (cust_email),
   CONSTRAINT cust_mobile_unq UNIQUE (cust_mobile),
   CONSTRAINT bank_id_for_key FOREIGN KEY (bank_id) REFERENCES bank (bankid)
);
```

However, I wouldn't bother with naming the `NOT NULL` constraints. Naming them doesn't really add very much manageability, as they can be updated by altering the table without knowing the name.